Very high pressure fluctuations in molecular dynamics
I'm performing molecular dynamics simulations through the TIP3F model for water in NpT ensemble. The pressure control is attained by using the bussi barostat, while the temperature one through the bussi thermostat. However, instantaneous pressure values as high as 1519.42 atm are obtained during the simulation. According to statistical mechanics, this doesn't make sense to me. I tried to change the coupling time constant of barostat, but I didn't obtain any significant changes. How could I solve this?

Can you include a structure / input file?  I suspect your system is small.  If so, fluctuations will be large.

Hi Tristan. When the system is too small, is it normal to have fluctuations vey high, in disagreement with statistical mechanics? I made a simulation with CHCl3 too. However, I obtained large fluctuations even when the system had (50 A)³ in volume. Then, I used nose-hoover barostat/thermostat and the problem was solved. But, for H2O, the problem persists.

I would say to systematically check this wrt. system size.  Look at the stdev of instant pressure.  The barostat can influence this, but you may be overdamping the fluctuations as well so be careful to understand check how things differ wrt. barostat settings as well

Does this help?  https://manual.gromacs.org/current/user-guide/terminology.html#pressure. and a related post - https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/large-pressure-fluctuations-in-molecular-dynamics

This question is similar to: Large pressure fluctuations in molecular dynamics. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
